# System.TimeoutException in code using C # Entity Framework 6 and PostgreSQL (NpgSQL)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I created a program to connect to PostgreSQL using Entity Framework 6 in a C# console app.

The app was running fine, but after about 5 hours the app suddenly stopped.

Since it stopped suddenly, I searched the log from the Windows Event Viewer to find out the cause and confirmed the error is a `System.TimeoutException`.

The code below is where the error occurred. It's a very simple code that just gets the current time and updates the table.

```
static void GetStartProcessTime()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var processingTimeTable = context.CheckprocessingTimeTable.First(x => x.id== 1);
        processingTimeTable.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However, there are multiple places to operate the DB in the program, and it is possible that an error occurred in this place by chance ...

The process was aborted because of an unhandled exception to the error that occurred. I am in trouble because I do not know exactly what was the cause.

Couldn't you connect to the DB to see the details of the error? I think, but I don't know where to investigate.

Also, this error doesn't happen every time, which is annoying to me.

I tried to find out if there were cases such as disconnection between Entity Framework and PostgreSQL, but I couldn't find a similar example.

Where should we check first in such cases?

I would like your advice.

Sorry for the poor English and the rudimentary questions.

```
    アプリケーション:EquipmentManagement.exe
フレームワークのバージョン:v4.0.30319
説明: ハンドルされない例外のため、プロセスが中止されました。
例外情報:System.TimeoutException
   場所 Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<Authenticate>d__0.MoveNext()
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<Open>d__148.MoveNext()
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 Npgsql.ConnectorPool+<AllocateLong>d__28.MoveNext()
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Result()
   場所 Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection+<>c__DisplayClass32_0+<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   場所 Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher+<>c.<Open>b__13_0(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dispatch[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.__Canon, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__55_0()
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(System.Action)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

例外情報:System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy, Boolean, Boolean)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass41_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResults>b__0()
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   場所 System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider+<>c__14`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetElementFunction>b__14_2(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   場所 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   場所 System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorl`enter code here`ib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>>)
   場所 EquipmentManagement.Operation.GetStartProcessTime()
   場所 EquipmentManagement.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Any time you connect to a database you need error handling, because there are a large number of different errors that can happen. I suggest you put each access to the DB in a `try` `catch` and log the errors.

Comment: thank you.  This is a rudimentary question, but in the content of the error log displayed in the event viewer of windows and the content of exception handling (for example, Exception.ToString ()), Exception.ToString () is still described in more detail. Is it there?

Comment: You tell me if it's there, I can't see your screen. Check the Windows Application log, there should be a stack trace attached to the event

Comment: thank you.  I don't have a screen at hand right now, so I don't remember what was written ...  However, I think that the error message "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException" was also included.  I'm sorry for the ambiguity.  I will comment again once I have the exact information.

Comment: Added the contents of the error log. i'm sorry that Japanese is Mixed.I was getting this error log when the application stopped.

Comment: It looks more like it's failing to connect to the database to me - `EnsureConnection` and `EntityConnection.Open()` - it's opening a connection to the database and failing. Make sure you've specified the database connection string somewhere in your app startup? As @Charlieface mentioned you can probably also wrap it in a try/catch and check the exception details there.

Comment: thank you.  The connection string is described in app.config as follows.  As advised, I also changed the code to put try / catch in every part that connects to the DB and output the log.  Is it common for a connection to fail suddenly after doing the same thing over and over for several hours?  <add name = "DatabaseConnectionString" connectionStrings = "Server = localhost; port = 5432; Database = MachineOne; User Id = postgres; Password = ****;" providerName = "Npgsql" />